# NX package-based repo: projectRoot vs workspaceRoot?

Tags: node.js, package.json, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

If I have a package-based monorepo with NX, which directory is `projectRoot`, and which one is `workspaceRoot`?

From the docs (https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration):

> {projectRoot} and {workspaceRoot}
>
> {projectRoot} is a key word that is replaced by the path to the current project's root directory. {workspaceRoot} is a key word that is replaced by the path to the workspace root directory.

This is hilariously obvious and unhelpful explanation. I want to know which one is which, given I have this directory structure:

```
(git repo root dir)
|
+- nx.json
+- package.json - it says `"workspaces": [ "packages/*" ]`
|
+- packages/
   |
   +- package1/
   +- package2/
```

Because `package.json` mentions my `packages/*` as "workspaces", my guess is that each package is a workspace, thus `workspaceRoot` must refer to each package individually, while `projectRoot` must refer to a top-level dir with my `nx.json` config. But I have absolutely no idea how to confirm this. I'm experimenting with cache (setting various `inputs` as seeing is it hits or misses), and absolutely nothing works.

To clarify what I'm confused about: Is "workspace root" a directory containing all the workspaces (i.e. packages), or does it mean "root directory of an individual workspace (i.e. package)." (Here I'm assuming that "workspace" == "package", which may not be true.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on reading https://nx.dev/concepts/mental-model, here are my definitions:

- "project" = each package, e.g. a library or an app, which refers to each individual subdirectory inside `packages/`
- "projectRoot" = root of each individual package. In the example from the question, it will be `packages/package1` and `packages/package2`
- "workspace" = collection of all the packages/projects. Note that "package.json" uses the word "workspaces" (plural) to refer to a directory with all the packages, which is what confuses me.
- "workspaceRoot" = the root directory where `nx.json` is located

In short:

- project = package
- workspace = collection of projects

Comment: The "workspaces" property in the package.json does not refer to the concept of an Nx workspace, instead it refers to npm/yarn workspaces (depending on the package manager you are using). Nx detects you are using npm/yarn/pnpm workspaces to scan packages and count them as projects in your <nx> workspace.